# Which astronomical objects do we have images of, taken at ground level?

Tags: photography

I am looking for images of astronomical objects taken at the ground level of the actual object, by something on the actual object, i.e. the Mars Rover.

Is this the complete list and accurate?.

- Earth
- Mars
- Titan
- Venus
- 67P/Churyumov-Gerasimenko
- Moon

*(I am not interested in images of objects take from the ground level of Earth).*

Comment: @Dean: The question is about images taken by a probe at ground level *on the body itself*, not taken from the ground on Earth. No probes have reached any bodies outside the Solar System.

Comment: What about Eros? There were some very close photos by [NEAR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEAR_Shoemaker) and data was collected from the surface, but I'm not sure surface photos were returned...

Comment: Start at [List of landings on extraterrestrial bodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_landings_on_extraterrestrial_bodies), then check what we have photos of

Comment: This is more of a Space Exploration (visiting other worlds) question than an Astronomy (observing other worlds from telescopes) question. Plus, it is already answered at Space Exploration: http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/9974/how-many-extraterrestrial-bodies-have-hosted-a-lander-which-returned-images

Comment: I don't think it would be fruitful for us to duplicate that good answer here, and as I said, I'm pretty sure the activities of robotic landers are off topic here.

Comment: @called2voyage, Fair enough if its answered on another exchange (didn't even know that existed) but I would say this question is still on topic given. `What topics can I ask about here? ...Data returned by space missions such as probes, rovers and satellites`

Comment: @JamesWood That is intended to include scientific data not necessarily ground images without a particular scientific context. The context here is mainly astronomy and planetary science. If the question had a planetary science context, then I might consider it more on topic.